# error during the Installation of maas-region-controller on a clear Ubuntu 14.04lts base server

Tags: 14.04, maas

I've tried to install the MaaS Region Controller via stable ppa on a clear ubuntu 14.04lts server using the command

```
sudo apt-get install maas-region-controller
```

but during the installation receive this error

```
| An error occurred while installing the database:                          │  
│                                                                           │  
│ psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory Is the       │  
│ server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket    │  
│ "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?**
...
Next step for database installation:                                        │  
│                                                                           │  
│                          abort                                            │  
│                          retry                                            │  
│                          retry (skip questions)                           │  
│                          ignore
```

is there someone had my same error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved that installed MaaS directly using an Ubuntu ISO clear and from boot selected MaaS.